# Unable to set object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting

> run time error 13, type mismatch.

I have the below code:

```
Dim wkbObj As Workbook
Other dims

Set wkbObj = GetObject(This Workbook.Path & "Contacts_SF. xlsx")
```

The above line is where the error occurs and I can't figure out why. Tried different variations to set the `wkbObj` but get similar errors.

Comment: Have you tried `Workbooks()` or `CreateObject()` (if it's not already open)?  I believe `GetObject()` would be: `Set wkbObj = GetObject("Contacts_SF. xlsx").Application`, since it's already open and you only need the name of the opened workbook.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get an error because of the spaces and I think you miss a backslash. But you can also use

`Set wkbObj = Application.Workbooks.Open(Thisworkbook.Path & "\Contacts_SF.xlsx")`

or if it is already open

`Set wkbObj = Application.Workbooks("Contacts_SF.xlsx")`

Comment: Thanks, worked fine opening the Workbook beforehand. Thanks again.